# I need help choosing the right c++ container

Tags: c++

key is :(x,y)  , that means 2 integers.

value is: 0 or 1.

And I have frequently operation of iteration of this hash map.

Which data structure is fit? I am using C++ stl or tr1. Don't consider boost.

Comment: what do you want to change/ gain?

Comment: He asked an honest question Mario, so don't nit pick. Remember English may not be his native language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the data format stored obviously is a bool.

And for the key format, if you would know the bitsize of those integers and performance is a must, I would use a associative array (called a `map` in C++) with twice the bitwidth integers as key:

```
bool val = true;
uint32 x, y; // key
uint64 combo = x << 32 + y;

std::map<uint64, bool> container;
```

But this would work fine too and is semantically **much** better:

```
std::map<std::pair<int, int>, bool> container.
```

Comment: one more question, so how can I use find() for this? is that "a.find(<x,y>)"? suppose a has defined.

Comment: `container.find(std::make_pair(x, y))`

Answer (score 3):

```
map< pair< int, int >, bool > cont;
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest the use of a proper hashmap (unlike std::map which **isn't** a hashmap):

```
typedef std::tr1::unordered_map<pair<int, int>, bool> MyContainer;
MyContainer m_myContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a std::hash_map or std::map.
I'm not sure which would give you faster performance though.